# How would you go about counting the number of rows in a CSV file which contain each unique value in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

My specification is as follows: Write code to count the number of records containing each source IP address, and the number of records containing each destination IP address. Generate histograms to visualise your results.

In short, I've got a CSV file with sourceIP and destIP as headers. I've managed to work out how many unique values there are total with:

```
sIP = data['sourceIP'].nunique()
```

but I want to somehow end up with all the unique IP's and the number of times each one occurs - with which I can then make a histogram.

I'm new to data science and pandas, and haven't been able to find any clear documentation that describes how to do the above effectively. I've got some ideas as to how you could do it by iterating through the column, adding unique IPs to one array, the frequency of each to another, and plot these (probably as a bar chart because a histogram doesn't make sense in this context) however I feel like this would be horrendously slow. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, the below is an example that may be able to help you out. Just replace `df` with your dataframe and the `A` column with `sourceIP`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'A': [10, 20, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
            'B': [11, 21, 10, 21, 30, 40, 50],
        }
    )
print(df['A'].value_counts())
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
uniqe_sourceIP =  data['sourceIP'].value_counts()
```